# Как удалить python и все что с ним связано(pip, IDLE, все библиотеки ранее скачанные)?

Tags: python, pip

У меня вечно какие-то проблемы с python и библиотеками, поэтому я собираюсь переустановить python и все что с ним связано. Однако, когда я пытался это сделать, удалился лишь сам python, а pip и все библиотеки установленные им остались. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как удалить все данные связанные с python?

ОС: Windows 10

Comment: Саму папку питона с либами чистили?

Comment: Ну и ещё: про какую ОС речь?

Comment: Я использую Windows

Comment: если есть время, то лучше выполните сброс Windows 10 до заводских настроек ''' в Windows 10 предусмотрен способ вернуть ОС в первоначальное состояние, сбросив систему до заводских настроек. Полный сброс очищает жесткий диск и переустанавливает Windows, поэтому никакие личные данные, программы и файлы не сохраняются.'''

Comment: А где эта папка с библиотеками находится если не сложно?

Comment: @Интик но мне не нужно возвращать Windows в исходное состояние из-за 1-ой программы.

Comment: @dimimir там где стоял сам Python. Удалите полностью его папку. Ещё почистите C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Local\pip

Comment: Спасибо, почистил. А вместе с python удалять python launcher?

Comment: regedit его хвосты находятся! если не секрет.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Заходим в переменные среды, через свойства компьютера. Удаляем оттуда всё что связано с питоном:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

2. Заходи в старую панель управления, удаление программ, и удаляем питон (пкм - удалить)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Так же удаляем Лаучеры, сторонние IDE и.т.п.

3.Открываем виртуалальные окружения и их тоже удаляем: (найти их можно по названию venv, Scrips)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

4. По умолчанию папка с питоном: `C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38` для новых версий.
   Библиотеки хранятся в папке Scripts. В принципе удаление питона через панель управления должно было само всё почистить, но если не почистила, вычищаем ее от библиотек.