# Закрыл инсталлер python, когда он уже почти установился

Tags: python, установка

Закрыл инсталлер питона, когда он уже почти установился. Теперь выдаёт ошибку 0x80070643, хотя я удалил его из приложений и по адресу установки. По этому гайду ничего не нашёл [Как удалить python и все что с ним связано(pip, IDLE, все библиотеки ранее скачанные)?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1136854/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-python-%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%B5-%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE-%D1%81-%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC-%D1%81%D0%B2%D1%8F%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BEpip-idle-%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%B5-%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0) . В этом видео пробовал оба способа, ничего не нашёл https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aaFOI3Zpu1U&t=278s . Я в компах полный ноль, помогите, пожалуйста.

Про ошибку из логов:

```
[1C4C:165C][2023-09-20T00:47:59]e000: Error 0x80070643: Failed to install MSI package.

[1C4C:165C][2023-09-20T00:47:59]e000: Error 0x80070643: Failed to configure per-user MSI package.

[1C4C:165C][2023-09-20T00:47:59]i319: Applied execute package: doc_JustForMe, result: 0x80070643, restart: None

[1C4C:165C][2023-09-20T00:47:59]e000: Error 0x80070643: Failed to execute MSI package.
```

Comment: Сперва в разделе "Приложения" (Apps) или "Приложения и компоненты" (Apps & Features) найдите Python в списке установленных программ. Выберите Python и нажмите "Удалить" (Uninstall). Если его там нет, то перейдите в директорию, в которую был установлен Python (обычно это `C:\Program Files\Python` или `C:\Users\<ваше имя>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python`) и убедитесь, что директория Python полностью удалена. Если нет то удалить вручную. После перезагрузите компьютер. Возможно может помочь.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но у меня не сработало

Comment: Что значит не сработало? Что выдаёт сейчас?

Comment: То же самое, ошибка 0x80070643. Хотя теперь процесс до ошибки длится дольше, не знаю, значит ли это что-то, вдруг да. Может ли быть проблема в галочке в инсталлере, которая связывает какие-то файлы с питоном?